# C# Table query using GoupBy based on maximum version value in Linq Method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-method-syntax

I have a table called "TB_USER_ROUTE" in which when I want to consult the information it shows the following result.

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| ID         | FK_CODE_TYPE         | A_SEQ              | A_IDNAME   | A_NAMEFULL      | A_VERSION|
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| 1          | 1                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 1       |
| 2          | 1                    | 2                  |       A3   | 075-12458969    | 1       |
| 3          | 2                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 1       |
| 4          | 4                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 1       |
| 5          | 4                    | 2                  |       A3   | 075-12458969    | 1       |
| 6          | 1                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 2       |
| 7          | 1                    | 2                  |       A3   | 075-12458969    | 2       |
```

But I want to know how to write a statement through LINQ Method C# to obtain the following result.

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| ID         | FK_CODE_TYPE         | A_SEQ              | A_IDNAME   | A_NAMEFULL      | A_VERSION|
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| 6          | 1                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 2       |
| 7          | 1                    | 2                  |       A3   | 075-12458969    | 2       |
| 3          | 2                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 1       |
| 4          | 4                    | 1                  |       A2   | 077-25000000    | 1       |
| 5          | 4                    | 2                  |       A3   | 075-12458969    | 1       |
```

What I am looking for is to create a statement that when called shows me in order all the FK_CODE_TYPE based on the maximum version existing in A_VERSION
That is, in the example I have 4 records with FK_CODE_TYPE = 1 but 2 are version "1" and the other 2 are version "2" so it should only show me those of the recent version
which in this case is "2" and so on with any FK_CODE_TYPE that has the higher version.

I use this code but only works to get the first result

```
var result = tblist.GroupBy(x => x.FK_CODE_TYPE, (key,g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.A_SEQ).First());
```

What should I do to get the results I'm looking for without using first()?

Comment: `tblist.GroupBy(x => x.FK_CODE_TYPE).SelectMany(g=>g.Where(x=>x.A_SEQ == g.Max(y=>y.A_SEQ )))` ?

Comment: That means you need the highest "A_VERSION" of each unique "FK_CODE_TYPE" without using First() method. correct?

Comment: At first your are grouping the elements of tblist by "FK_CODE_TYPE" column. @Selvin your code actaully filters the collection data set to get the records/data with the maximum "A_SEQ" for each "FK_CODE_TYPE" group. And my approach will be to filter the collection set based on highest "A_VERSION" and then orders them by "A_SEQ"

Comment: `var result = tblist.GroupBy(x => x.FK_CODE_TYPE).SelectMany(group => group.Where(item => item.A_VERSION == group.Max(g => g.A_VERSION)).OrderBy(item => item.A_SEQ) ).OrderBy(item =>item.FK_CODE_TYPE).ThenBy(item => item.A_VERSION);`

Comment: @DebugCode It's correct.

Comment: @Selvin I appreciate your contribution but as DebugCode mentions, it only filters with maximum seq

Comment: @DebugCode Thanks ! Works like a charm, Can you post your comment as answer in order to upvote and set correct answer?

Comment: of course this solution will create really wierd SQL query (with "select from subselect table with max **cross join table where join conditions** ") ... better would be `tblist.Join(tblist.GroupBy(x => x.FK_CODE_TYPE).Select(g => new { FK_CODE_TYPE = g.Key, A_VERSION = g.Max(x => x.A_VERSION) }), x => new { x.FK_CODE_TYPE, x.A_VERSION}, x=>new { x.FK_CODE_TYPE, x.A_VERSION}, (outer, inner) => outer)` - which would be use "select from table inner join subselect table with max" - which looks like what we would do in SQL(eventually we would use  exists)

Comment: [Comparsion of generated SQL type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWLkP.png)